# How does one install the FFTW package under Fedora and get Octave to recognize it as loaded?

Tags: installation, octave, fedora, fftw

All the references to FFTW in Octave make it sound like it is a package only for Octave (not quite true, but close), and give instructions for installing a tar.gz file by typing on the Octave command line, "pkg install ". But the FFTW website itself says to either use RPM, or better yet, your own distributions package. Well, Fedora does have a package for it, named (surprise) 'fftw'. But after installing this with yum, I still have no idea what name to use on the Octave command line with the pkg install command: the obvious 'fftw' doesn't work. And there is no /etc/fftw directory created, either (I forget which directions said this should have happened, but it didn't).

So what is my next step after installing the Fedora package? I'm not going to need to build FFTW from source, am I?

Comment: How did you installed Octave? isn't Octave on fedora's repo?

Comment: Octave has been installed for so long, I don't remember how it got on there. But yum lists it as coming from anaconda-InstallationRepo-201005130056.i386. It is version 3.2.4, release 2.fc13. And it lists no packages installed under "pkg list". Even after "yum install fftw".

Comment: Install it using brew